# How can the set A = {(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)} be proven to be transitive using the alternative definition?

Tags: relations

I understand how this satisfies the definition typically used for ordered pairs. But how does this satisfy the requirement that every element $x$ in $A$ must be a subset of set $A$? I know that $A$ can also be written as $\{\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}, \{\{b\}, \{b, c\}\}, \{\{a\}, \{a, c\}\}\}$, but fail to see how every element of this is subset of $A$, and furthermore how $\{\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}, \{\{b\}, \{b, c\}\}, \{\{c\}, \{c, a\}\}\}$, for instance, differs in any substantial way. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: They aren't "alternative definitions". They are definitions of *different concepts* that use the same word. Sets are "transitive" when the relation "is an element of" is a transitive relation on a particular set, so that the set $A$ is transitive if and only if for all $x,y$, if $x\in y$ and $y\in A$, then $x\in A$. This is a different concept than the concept of an equivalence relation on a set $X$ being transitive (though the name is derived from the same idea, as noted above). Your set $A$ defines a transitive relation on $\{a,b,c\}$, but is not a transitive set.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. I was very confused on this, thanks.

Comment: This occurs several times throughout mathematics.  The word ["Normal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal#Mathematics) for instance appears no fewer than $20$ times to be used to describe entirely different concepts.